# Apache config leads https to http and then to https

Tags: apache, https

Apache configuration

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule (.) https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

Header always merge Vary X-Forwarded-Proto
```

gives

```
 
https://example.com/foo/bar --> http://example.com/foo/bar/ --> https://example.com/foo/bar/
```

How do I fix that?

Comment: if it was http:// --> http --> https, it would sound like the issue is you have an automatic redirect to add trailing /, but I wouldn't think this would drop https; do you have any other rules somewhere else?  (And just to check... does going to http://example.com/foo/bar/ properly get redirected (without funniness) directly to https://example.com/foo/bar/ ?

Comment: Going to example.com/foo/bar does this. `https://example.com/foo/bar --> http://example.com/foo/bar/ --> https://example.com/foo/bar/`